# How do I dynamically generate a select menu in my `_navigation.html.erb`, preferrably with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I want to generate a `<select>` menu of `Vendor` options in my `_navigation.html.erb` partial that will show up on every page.

This is the HTML I would like to produce:

```
<form>
 <select>
    <option value="">Browse by Store</option>           
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Deisel">Deisel</option>
    <option value="NIke">Nike </option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Then once someone chooses a vendor, it takes them to the equivalent of `vendors_path(@vendor)`. If I were trying to do this in a regular form_partial, I would simply do something like:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :vendors %>
<% end %>
```

But...I would then declare some way for that `@product` to be handled in the controller that governs the view that this form is rendered on.

How do I do that in the `/layouts/_navigation.html.erb`?

And...how do I generate the link functionality, that when they choose the `vendor` they want, it automatically redirects them to that `vendor/:id` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you do you want to use a form to build theses links, and also why use theses links with your application controller. If you want to change links displayed by each product page you can do it this way :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle"
   data-toggle="dropdown"
   href="#">
   Navigation with Vendors by Product
     <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <% @product.vendors.each do |vendor| %>
  <li><%= link_to vendor.name, vendor %></li>
  <%end%>
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Use this partial into your show view product.

Assuming those models :
product.rb

```
has_many :brands
has_many :vendors, :through => :brands
```

vendor.rb

```
has_many :brands
has_many :products, :through => :brands
```

brand.rb

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :vendor
```

If you just need a partial menu with all vendors you can also do it this way :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle"
   data-toggle="dropdown"
   href="#">
    General Navigation Vendors
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <% Vendor.all.each do |vendor| %>
  <li><%= link_to vendor.name, vendor %></li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
```

If you want to load all Vendors into your application_controller, maybe you can use before_filter :load_vendors

```
 def load_vendors
  @vendors = Vendor.all
 end
```

Comment: Perfect.....you are right. I don't need to get all fancy, all I really needed was the dropdown menu and I was thinking a form. Silly me. That `ul class="dropdown-menu"` is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks much meng!

Answer (score 0):

Put your controller code in your application_controller.rb then create a folder in your views folder called application and put your partial files inside that.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance

I'm not familiar with simple form but railscasts also has a nice how to on using simple form.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form-revised